# Quartz .NET The instance of entity type 'TABLENAME' cannot be tracked because

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, quartz.net

We have built an API with .NET Core 3.1 that extracts data from an Excel and stores it via
EF Core into a MS SQL database. We use Quartz. NET so that it is handled in a background thread. For DI we use Autofac.

We use Scoped Services to be able to use the DBContext via DI (as described here https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-quartz-net-hosted-service-with-asp-net-core/).

Unfortunately, saving the data still does not work when multiple users are using the application at the same time. We get the following error message:

```
The instance of entity type 'TABLENAME' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'TABLEKEY'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

Here our related code:

Startup.cs

```
      // Add DbContext
     services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("XY.Infrastructure")));

      // Add Quartz
      services.AddQuartz(q =>
      {
        // as of 3.3.2 this also injects scoped services (like EF DbContext) without problems
        q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();

        // these are the defaults
        q.UseSimpleTypeLoader();
        q.UseDefaultThreadPool(tp =>
        {
          tp.MaxConcurrency = 24;
        });
      });

      services.AddQuartzServer(options =>
      {
        // when shutting down we want jobs to complete gracefully
        options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
      });

      // Add Services
      services.AddHostedService<QuartzHostedService>();
      services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, SingletonJobFactory>();
      services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
      services.AddTransient<ImportJob>();

      services.AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
      services.AddScoped<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
```

Logic.cs

```
// Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
        var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        var scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

        var parameters = new JobDataMap()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("request", message),
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("sales", sales),
        };

        var jobId = $"processJob{Guid.NewGuid()}";
        var groupId = $"group{Guid.NewGuid()}";

        // defines the job
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ImportJob>()
            .WithIdentity(jobId, groupId)
            .UsingJobData(parameters)
            .Build();

        // defines the trigger
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity($"Trigger{Guid.NewGuid()}", groupId)
            .ForJob(job)
            .StartNow()
            .Build();

        // schedule Job
        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        // and start it off
        await scheduler.Start();
```

QuartzHostedService.cs

```
public class QuartzHostedService : IHostedService
  {
    private readonly ISchedulerFactory _schedulerFactory;
    private readonly IJobFactory _jobFactory;
    private readonly ILogger<QuartzHostedService> _logger;
    private readonly IEnumerable<JobSchedule> _jobSchedules;

    public QuartzHostedService(
        ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory,
        IJobFactory jobFactory,
        IEnumerable<JobSchedule> jobSchedules,
        ILogger<QuartzHostedService> logger)
    {
      _schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
      _jobSchedules = jobSchedules;
      _jobFactory = jobFactory;
      _logger = logger;
    }
    public IScheduler Scheduler { get; set; }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      try
      {
        Scheduler = await _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler(cancellationToken);
        Scheduler.JobFactory = _jobFactory;

        foreach (var jobSchedule in _jobSchedules)
        {
          var job = CreateJob(jobSchedule);
          var trigger = CreateTrigger(jobSchedule);

          await Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger, cancellationToken);
        }

        await Scheduler.Start(cancellationToken);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
      }
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      await Scheduler?.Shutdown(cancellationToken);
    }

    private static IJobDetail CreateJob(JobSchedule schedule)
    {
      var jobType = schedule.JobType;
      return JobBuilder
          .Create(jobType)
          .WithIdentity(jobType.FullName)
          .WithDescription(jobType.Name)
          .Build();
    }

    private static ITrigger CreateTrigger(JobSchedule schedule)
    {
      return TriggerBuilder
          .Create()
          .WithIdentity($"{schedule.JobType.FullName}.trigger")
          .StartNow()
          .Build();
    }
  }
```

SingletonJobFactory.cs

```
public class SingletonJobFactory : IJobFactory
  {
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public SingletonJobFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
      _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
      try
      {
        return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType) as IJob;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw;
      }
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job) { }
  }
```

Importjob.cs

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
  public class ImportJob : IJob
  {
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;
    private readonly ILogger<ImportJob> _logger;

    public ImportJob(IServiceProvider provider, ILogger<ImportJob> logger)
    {
      _provider = provider;
      _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
      try
      {
        using (var scope = _provider.CreateScope())
        {
          var jobType = context.JobDetail.JobType;
          var job = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(jobType) as IJob;

          var repo = _provider.GetRequiredService<MYRepository>();
          var importFactSales = _provider.GetRequiredService<IImportData>();

          var savedRows = 0;
          var request = (MyRequest)context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("request");
          var sales = (IEnumerable<MyData>)context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("sales");

          await importFactSales.saveValidateItems(repo, request, sales, savedRows);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You seem to have a lot of custom components that seem unnecessary, have you checked https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/main/src/Quartz.Examples.AspNetCore/Startup.cs ? Quartz has built-in hosted service (services.AddQuartzServer()), you don't need to create own job factory either. Why don't you inject dependencies like MYRepository via job constructor - no need for IServiceProvider  or custom scopes?

Comment: @MarkoLahma thanks for your comment. without own job factory, i wasn't able to create IJob Instances (Error: Cannot instantiate type which has no empty constructor). Any idea to fix this issue ? I would like to use the built-in hosted service from quartz.

Comment: If you check the example application and follow its constructs it should work. As you can see the example uses jobs that get dependencies injected via constructor. Make sure you use latest release of Quartz too.

Can it be that you are adding the jobs manually, Quartz callback has the `AddJob` methods. As said, everything you register under `// Add Services` which is scheduler related seems redundant.

Comment: @MarkoLahma Yes the jobs are added manually (see Logic.cs above) and we're using Autofac as DI library. I am already using the latest version (3.3.3).

Comment: @MarkoLahma i still haven't got it right. i've created an example project with the latest Quartz Version and Autofac. the solution has the same project structure as the original.  My code is available under https://github.com/zugcorm/Quartz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution in the meantime. As @marko-lahma described in the comment, use the built-in hosted service and don't implement your own JobFactory.

- Remove the SingletonJobFactory.cs and QuartzHostedService.cs
- Use the [Autofac.Extras.Quartz](https://github.com/alphacloud/Autofac.Extras.Quartz) and Quartz.Extensions.Hosting Nuget Package
- Don't use CreateScope anymore, inject all needed Dependencies over the Constructor
- Register QuartzAutofacFactoryModule and QuartzAutofacJobsModule in the Startup.